# How do I change the border color on a TWebButton component?

Tags: delphi, button, border, tms-web-core, border-color

I'm able to change the button's background color using the `Color` property on the component, but I don't see a property to change the border color.

You can see here that the button has a border, but I'm not sure how to change the border color in Delphi:

[image: Delphi TWebButton]

Comment: In the Q you ask for a component property, but your answer doesn't serve one either. It re-answers (just like multiple of your previous As to Qs) how to use `.ElementHandle` again and again, without recognizing it's your portal to a browser's [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#JavaScript). Get your hands on JS in a website and you'll discover everything's there already.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a property to change this in design-time, So you'll have to change it dynamically during run-time.

In the `OnCreate` event of the form, you can write:

```
WebButton1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('border-color', 'red');
```

The first parameter, you pass in the `border-color` CSS property, and the second parameter you pass in the HTML Color:

[image: Delphi TWebButton with red border]

Comment: This is ridiculous - every web designer using JS knows this. FOR DECADES! Stop spamming Q+As for every single DOM property - [it's already there to look up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color). On top the CSS property `border-color` knows more than only one parameter. `.style` is the gate to **everything** on CSS, just like `.document` and `.navigator` have their scopes well known to everyone using JS in websites. Just refer to web development in general - TMS is certainly not reinventing all that.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, but the question is whether there's a Delphi way. Ideally, I'd like to do it without JS and without CSS. Just using Delphi. I just answered the CSS way since it is applied via Delphi and the first method that I found. If you know a different way, feel free to post an answer. Ideally, I'd like to do it in just Delphi without the `style` method.

Comment: "_I'd like to do it without JS and without CSS_" makes little sense when having a "Web" GUI, not to speak components. Look at the type of `.ElementHandle` and reconsider if anything beyond that can be called "Delphi" at all. Why should a component have hundreds of properties when the interface already provides access to everything that is already standardized by CSS means?

Comment: I'm not sure if SO was designed to be a question + self answer site, at least not in the way you're using it.  I don't bother answering questions that you post because I know you'll answer it yourself.  Like, it seams you already know the answer when you post the question.  I can appreciate your love of Delphi and don't want to discourage you. But I would appreciate if you could post questions that you really need help with.