# How do I change the colors of the scrollbar on a TWebScrollBox component?

Tags: css, delphi, scrollbar, tms, tms-web-core

I have a `TWebScrollBox` with lots of elements in it, but I don't like the colors of the default scrollbar in it.

This is my scrollbar on the `TWebScrollBox`:

[image: Scrollbar on TWebScrollBox]

You can see the scrollbar consists of two different parts:

- A white-ish background color
- And a gray foreground scroll and arrows.

I want to change the color for both of the above two parts.

I looked for a scrollbar color property, but couldn't find one.

Is it somehow possible to change the colors on the scrollbar without using a CSS file or CSS class? I want to do it just simply using Delphi code.

Comment: Asking how to define CSS again like in [How do I set inline CSS to a component via Delphi in TMS Web Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77251540/4299358) and [How do I change the border color on a TWebButton component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77294154/4299358) and previous Qs.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the scrollbar colors using the following code:

```
WebScrollBox.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('scrollbar-color','Fuchsia Green');
```

And this can be turned into a nice Delphi procedure as follows:

```
procedure ChangeScrollbarColor(ScrollBox: TWebCustomPanel; ColorThumb, ColorTrack: TColor);
var
  RGB: Integer;
  ColorThumbHex, ColorTrackHex: String;
begin
  RGB := ColorToRGB(ColorThumb);
  ColorThumbHex := '#' + Byte(RGB).ToHexString +
                  Byte(RGB shr 8).ToHexString +
                  Byte(RGB shr 16).ToHexString;

  RGB := ColorToRGB(ColorTrack);
  ColorTrackHex := '#' + Byte(RGB).ToHexString +
                Byte(RGB shr 8).ToHexString +
                Byte(RGB shr 16).ToHexString;

  ScrollBox.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('scrollbar-color',ColorThumbHex + ' ' + ColorTrackHex);
end;
```

This procedure can then easily be used to change the colors of a scrollbar in a `TWebScrollBox` component. The function is very nice, because you can pass in normal Delphi `TColor` values to it instead of needing to use HTML Colors.

Here's an example:

```
begin
  ChangeScrollbarColor(MyScrollBox, clFuchsia, clGreen);
end;
```

[image: TWebScrollBox with custom colors on scrollbar]

Comment: @AmigoJack It's not spamming. I provide an actual Delphi procedure that can be used to change the scrollbar color. This isn't a CSS answer. I wanted a way to do it with just Delphi code which is what the answer provides.

Comment: This is again a [`.ElementHandle.style.setProperty()` answer like before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294154/how-do-i-change-the-border-color-on-a-twebbutton-component/77294155#comment136265660_77294155). Turning a `TColor` into a HTML hex color is trivial. If "_this isn't a CSS answer_" then you cannot make use of `scrollbar-color` since [that **is** CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color).